# Excel function or tool? Finding all pairs that add up to specified sum

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of hundreds of random dollar amounts on one workbook (Sheet A) that I copy and paste in another workbook (Sheet B).
I subtract the sum of all amounts on sheet A from those pasted on Sheet B with the intention of getting 0.00 (which means I'm not missing any entries). On occasion, there is a difference and this difference is usually a total of many of the dollar amounts from one sheet or the other. Since it's a *sum* of these amounts, I'm not able to search (Ctrl + F) the difference.

Is there a function or tool in excel that will go through the dollar amount column on either workbook and highlight the possible options/ pairs of numbers that add up to that difference amount?

Comment: Why not just use COUNTIF to see if the entries from one sheet are present on the other?

Comment: Try : sort both column by amount... then put it side by side.. start compare.. the moment there is a mismatch.. you can see it directly.. then only "(Ctrl + F) the difference". ( :